# Distribute Value by Row Percentage in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a category, percentage table in SQL (the table itself has been obtained by the following query:

```sql
SELECT p.category, 
       sum(p.sales) * 100 / sum(sum(p.sales)) OVER () AS percentage
FROM product p
GROUP BY p.category;
```

| Category | Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| Books | 20.51% |
| Clocks | 9.49% |
| Pens | 60.2% |
| Desks | 9.8% |

How can I spread $100 (whole dollars, no cents) across the categories by percentage keeping in mind the GROUP BY and windows functions already in the query.

Intended Solution:

| Category | Percentage | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Books | 20.51% | 21 |
| Clocks | 9.49% | 9 |
| Pens | 60.2% | 60 |
| Desks | 9.8% | 10 |

I have been googling but I can't seem to find a similar scenario.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and do what explained there

Comment: You already calculated the `Percentage`, just multiply with the amount `100` will give you the required value

Comment: @Squirrel omg, forgot I could just reuse the percentage query... thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [*could*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77356781/distribute-value-by-row-percentage-in-sql/77356901#comment136374809_77356781) just `round()` the percentages you already have because they already sum up nicely to a 100 when rounded, but that's because `Books` round up and `Clocks` round down, balancing each others' rounding errors out. If you lose that balance, you'll get `Amounts` summing up to less than a 100 or more than a 100: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ecyEE8Mc)

```sql
SELECT category
    ,p::numeric(5,2) AS percentage
    ,(sum(p%1)over()::int >= row_number()over() )::int + trunc(p) AS amount
FROM ( SELECT category, 
              sum(sales)*100/sum(sum(sales))over() AS p
       FROM product
       GROUP BY category) a;
```

This distributes the rounding remainders evenly. You can also round all values until the last one and make the last one catch the remainders. Some banks and insurance companies prefer to set up installments this way:

```sql
SELECT category
      ,percentage::numeric(5,2)
      ,case when lead(percentage)over() is null
            then (sum(percentage%1)over()+floor(percentage))::int
            else floor(percentage)::int
       end AS amount 
FROM ( SELECT p.category, 
              sum(p.sales)*100/sum(sum(p.sales))over() AS percentage
       FROM product p
       GROUP BY p.category) a
```

Use of [`floor()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#id-1.5.8.9.6.2.2.11.1.1.1) keeps the remainder sum positive to avoid that last one dropping below 0.

Answer (score 0):

To split $100 across categories by percentage as fairly as possible:

```sql
SELECT category, round(pct, 2) AS percentage
     , trunc(pct) + (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY mod(pct, 1) DESC, category) 
                     <= 100 - sum(trunc(pct)) OVER ())::int AS amount
FROM  (
   SELECT p.category
        , sum(p.sales) * 100 / sum(sum(p.sales)) OVER () AS pct
   FROM   product p
   GROUP  BY p.category
   ) sub;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vh3abnRR)

The specific difficulty is that rounded percentages can sum up to more or less than $100. So assign the minimum share (= truncated percentage) in a first round, and then add $1 to the highest remainders in order until the $100 are spent.

If categories tie for a remaining buck (identical percentages), alphabetic sort order serves as tiebreaker in my query. Adjust any way you want.

The fiddle has more details.

I based my query on a single table `products`, as presented in the question. In actuality, there will be at least a second table `orders` in a 1:n relationship. Adjust accordingly. The principle query is the same.